# Проверка данных списком

Tags: excel

Есть документ в котором:
**A1** - список (Проверка данных),
**D1** - данные списка (до ста позиций:D100),
**E1** - дополнение к списку( столько же позиций сколько в самом списке **D1**:D100)
**B1** - ячейка для отображения дополнительной информации.

Необходимо при выборе из списка (A1) записать в ячейку B1 дополнительную информацию выбранных данных, т.е. если я в списке выбираю D55, то в B1 отобразилась Е55 и так далее (если А1=D55, то В1=Е55) как то так. Через Если(Или... такой список не обработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ВПР справится

=ВПР(A1;D$1:E$100;2;)